# how can i export access data filternig data and columns to excel

Tags: ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

i have a big access DB with many columns and over 2000 rows.
sometimes I need to export data to excel to send letters and etc.
but each time its a differet data, like:

1. most of times i dont need all the columns, like when i send letters i need just name and address and not all the info.
2. not always I need all data, like just clients from one city, or above buying sum and etc.

is there a way to make a simple form or something else, that will contain the option to select which columns and which data to export?

i made querys, but i need each and every time to change them according to the actual need.
i need something that will give me the option to just select from the different columns which i want to export, and from those who i do export just the info i need...